# How to deploy rails application to mutil servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have to 3 servers, i plan to use one for nginx, others for rails passenger , i want to know how to config ? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/), it's a very handy tool to help deploying Rails applications to multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used Capistrano Multistage https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

Works well for 2 environments. Staging and production; I assume that it work well with more.